# How to use select (dropdown) tag in Elm lang

Tags: drop-down-menu, html-select, dropdown, elm

I want to render simple dropdown within my elm app with the following code but it's not working as expected. I want to keep union type Role in place and avoid using strings if it's possible.

What's the best way to work with dropdown in Elm? I didn't find any example yet.

```
import Html exposing (..)
import Html.App exposing (beginnerProgram)
import Html.Events exposing (..)
import Html.Attributes exposing (..)
import Json.Decode

main =
  beginnerProgram
    { model = initialModel
    , view = view
    , update = update
    }

initialModel =
  { role = None
  }

type Role
  = None
  | Admin
  | User

type alias Model = 
  { role: Role
  }

type Msg
  = SelectRole Role


update msg model =
  case msg of
    SelectRole role ->
      { model | role = role }


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  div
    []
    [ select
        [ ]
        [ viewOption None
        , viewOption Admin
        , viewOption User
        ]
    , pre [] [ text <| toString model ]
    ]



viewOption : Role -> Html Msg
viewOption role =
  option
    [ onClick (SelectRole role) ]
    [ text <| toString role ]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `onClick` handler doesn't really work with `option` elements. You'll instead want to capture the `change` event and look at the JSON `targetValue` to see what was selected.

I would first remove the `onClick` handler and instead set the `option` tag's `value` attribute:

```elm
viewOption : Role -> Html Msg
viewOption role =
  option
    [ value <| toString role ]
    [ text <| toString role ]
```

Now you'll need a JSON Decoder that can take the event's `targetValue` string and convert it to a `Role`:

```elm
targetValueRoleDecoder : Json.Decode.Decoder Role
targetValueRoleDecoder =
  targetValue `Json.Decode.andThen` \val ->
    case val of
      "Admin" -> Json.Decode.succeed Admin
      "User" -> Json.Decode.succeed User
      "None" -> Json.Decode.succeed None
      _ -> Json.Decode.fail ("Invalid Role: " ++ val)
```

Now you just need to add that to the `select` `change` event handler:

```elm
    [ select
        [ on "change" (Json.Decode.map SelectRole targetValueRoleDecoder)
        ]
        [ viewOption None
        , viewOption Admin
        , viewOption User
        ]
```

The fact that we have to resort to strings is merely an artifact of having to translate values from DOM events into valid union types. You'll still want to keep `Role` as a union type; you just have to create JSON decoders targeting each union type for now, since Elm does not (yet) support any kind of automatic String to Union Type function.

Comment: Note that `Html.Attributes.onInput` will also work for most browsers, but you need `onChange` for IE!!!!!

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to format comments.  The above targetValueRoleDecoder did not compile for me with Elm 0.19 but the following did:      targetValueRoleDecoder : Json.Decode.Decoder Role
targetValueRoleDecoder =
  targetValue |> Json.Decode.andThen  (\val ->
    case val of
      "Admin" -> Json.Decode.succeed Admin
      "User" -> Json.Decode.succeed User
      "None" -> Json.Decode.succeed None
      _ -> Json.Decode.fail ("Invalid Role: " ++ val)
     )

Comment: For people looking for a more modern/recent answer to this question, as alluded to by a previous commenter, you can find an example for `onInput` usage in a form selector on the official elm lang examples page: https://elm-lang.org/examples/forms